# image gallery using For i =1 to ... doesn't use the CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

So I have an image gallery of 50 images that is generated by randomly picking 50 pics out of a pool of 500.

The code below works nicely but the images don't use the CSS style of the HTML file it is injected in, which includes a bigger preview of the image when hovering over it.
How could I get it to work?

Thank you

I have this:

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;
    
    document.body.appendChild(img); 
}

for (let i = 1; i<=50;i++ )
 {
    j= Math.floor((Math.random() * 500)+1);
     source='config/images/file_name_'+j+'.jpg';
    show_image(source,100, 100,'File_name_ #'+j);
   
 }
```

Gallery code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="Gallery" content="device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Icon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="config/menu2-1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
 
         <div class="texte"></box><a>Gallery description.</a></div>
  
  <div class="img-gallery">   


  <script src="Gallery.js">  </script>        


</div>
  
   
  
    </body>
    
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    background: #C0DDF4;
    font-family:  Cochin,Cambria, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    line-height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}


.img-gallery{
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
 
  left: 25%;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-gallery img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
} 

.img-gallery img:hover{
  transform: scale(3 ) rotate(-0deg) translateX(-10px) translateY(-10px);
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: I don't think we've got enough code shown for us to see the problem. How/where is the img appended to the HTML and what CSS is there?

Comment: I update the post with the gallery code

Comment: Also, the CSS style works fine when using static images.

Comment: Alright, I found a solution. I was making my life more complicated than it need to be. Got it with a simple document.write.